# SQlite - função semelhante PROCV para update

Tags: sql, sqlite

Boa tarde, creio que minha dúvida seja simples, porém após muitas pesquisas, não obtive êxito, e peço a ajuda de vcs.
Tenho a seguinte tabela no sqlite:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AASB201012 | 99,99 | null | BBBsss2010 |
| ARSB201020 | 19,99 | null | ARSB20107 |
| BBBsss2010 | 89,99 | null | ARSDKS207 |

Eu preciso que a coluna C seja atualizada com o valor do B quando o valor do D for encontrado no A
Se fosse no excel seria, o update no primeiro valor da coluna C ficaria algo como procv(D1;A:B;2;FALSO)

Pelo que andei pesquisando, seria algo com INNER JOIN etc, porém to tentando tentando e nada

Edit: Eu aplicando o update que pretendo, no exemplo o primeiro valor da coluna C seria atualizado desta maneira

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AASB201012 | 99,99 | *89,99* | *BBBsss2010* |
| ARSB201020 | 19,99 | null | ARSB20107 |
| *BBBsss2010* | *89,99* | null | ARSDKS207 |

Grato pela ajuda!

Comment: todos os dados estão na mesma tabela? não seria um update simples?

Comment: Estão sim, na mesma tabela, creio que nao é um update simples (ao menos pra mim não esta sendo simples kkkk).

Comment: Pelo que entendi do seu problema, vai ser algo assim: `UPDATE <nome-da-tabela> SET VLR-7 = VLR WHERE CODDATA-7 = CODDATA;`

Comment: Então, na vdd não é, eu preciso percorrer todas as linhas da tabela, e no campo VLR-7 preciso pegar o valor correspondente em CODDATA-7 e procurar ele na coluna CODDATA e com isso pegar o VLR da linha que achou, e jogar no VLR-7

Answer (score -3):

Vamos lá, primeiro criei uma tabela parecida com a sua, veja:

> create table if not exists tabelax(id integer primary key, coddata text not null, vlr text not null, vlr7 text not null, coddata7 text not null);

Depois efetuamos o update condicional, onde todas as colunas coddata7 tiverem seu conteudo igual ao de coddata, entao vlr7 recebe o valor da coluna vlr, logo temos o SQL:

> update tabelax set vlr7=vlr where coddata7=coddata;

Resultado da atualização(update):

```
1|AASB201012|99,99|   |BBBsss2010
2|ARSB201020|19,99|   |ARSB20107
3|BBBsss2010|89,99|   |ARSDK207
```

Veja, sei que copiei errado o primeiro item, mas foi propositalmente, se não fizesse isso não alteraria nada que fosse perceptivel, pois o primeiro que você informou eh BBBss2010 com 2 S, logo manteria 89,90, coloquei 1 s a mais para ter uma coluna igual a coddata pelo menos e assim você perceber alguma mudança.

Comment: Então amigo, desta maneira não atualiza conforme desejo, pois nunca o valor da ultima coluna vai coincidir com o da primeira na mesma linha, eu editei a tabela alterando os nomes da coluna, pra talvez ficar mais clara a minha duvida. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Está exatamente de acordo com o que você especificou, segue: UPDATE tableX SET c=b WHERE D=A, onde D é a colunacoddata7, A é a coluna coddata, C é a coluna vlr7 e b é a coluna vlr. Para efetuar esse teste no seu SQLite3 tive de chamar de retirar o - no nome da coluna porque o SQLite3 barrou, faz o teste e veja que o SQL esta correto.

Comment: Entao brother, eu testei, a questão é que na minha tabela, nunca o valor em A e em D coincidirão na mesma linha, e sim em outra, isso que ta pegando